# Inherit from const class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

I would like to inherit from a class with the `const` specifier like this:

```
class Property
{
    int get() const;
    void set(int a);
};

class ConstChild : public const Property
{
    // Can never call A::set() with this class, even if
    // the instantiation of this class is not const
};

class NonConstChild : public Property
{
    // Can call both A::set() and A::get() depending on 
    // the constness of instantiation of this class
};
```

My compiler obviously gives me an error for the `const` keyword in the second classes declaration. Ideally I'd like to avoid having to create a new class `ReadOnlyProperty` from which `ConstChild` would inherit.

**Can I somehow use the `const` keyword for inheritance?**

- If not, do you have any other ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You could equip `ConstChild` with a factory method as the only way to construct instances by making the constructor `private`. If it returns `const` references you would be about there.

Comment: Use aggregation over inheritance.

Comment: @thomas-b-preusser The point of this is to enable `ConstChild` to have `const` and non-`const` methods itself, i.e. have to have instantiations of that class that are constant and non-constant, while the `Property`-ness of that class will always be constant, i.e. the `set` method cannot ever be called on it.

Comment: @MartinDarterson hence Shane's suggestion

Comment: @shane-lu Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @ShaneLu Please expand that into an answer, as I suspect it's a lot closer to the intended result than any others so far. Martin: I won't answer this myself (yet?) to give Shane a chance, but suffice it to say they meant that you should include the 'base' as a member through aggregation, rather than by inheritance. As a member, it can be declared `const` with trivial ease.

Comment: What is the use case of a const child without having a mutable property in the first place (not using a constructor taking a mutable property) ?

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, a rationale would be illustrative and probably help inspire people to think of additional suggestions (if there are any). I mean: What is `Child`? Is it _really_ a `Property`, or is it something that _has_ one or more `Property`s? i.e.: Does it satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle? Either way, how to functionally achieve what you want, as written (i.e. without redesigning `Property`), is as Shane said: use composition (aggregation) to include `Property` member(s), which can then be `const`-qualified. If you 'must' use inheritance, then Thomas is right. Can't have both!

Comment: The problem with this, you can always cast back to the base cast and thus cast away constness without a nice visible `const_cast<>()` that would automatically get your CR rejected. For private inheritance it'd make (some) sense, but then you can really use aggregates.

Comment: You could specialize types eg. unit<complex<T>> or unit<quaternion<T>> for  interface or performance.  Down cast and mutability would possibly destroy the invariance. Currently the only way is to add an conversation operator to const base & to the non derived unit class,  bu the member access Syntax is not possible only free standing functions: real(c) but not c.real().

Answer (score 8):

Introduce mutability later in your inheritance tree and derive appropriately:

```
class Property
{
    int get() const;
};
class MutableProperty : public Property {
{
    void set(int a);
};
```

And then:

```
class ConstChild : public Property { ... };
class MutableChild : public MutableProperty { ... };
```

Comment: I realize that this is a solution to the problem itself, though I specified that I would prefer not to create a separate class `ReadOnlyProperty`, which is exactly what this is, just with different names.

Comment: Grant - although your naming would have been really undesirable as a `Property` would also be a `ReadOnlyProperty` while not being read-only.In the end, I am afraid you are truly asking for a new language feature then. And it is not unreasonable to imagine all the modifiers allowed for regular members to go with superclasses as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had the need for a related problem, which is: to really control/highlight mutable and const access on some class.
I did it with this simple reusable template wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
class TAccessor : private T
{
public:
    const T&    Const() const { return *this; }
    T&          Mutable() { return *this; }
};

// Example of use:
template <typename T>
using MyVector = TAccessor<std::vector<T>>;


void main()
{
    MyVector<int> vector;

    vector.Mutable().push_back(10);

    int x = vector.Const()[1];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to inherit from a class with the const specifier"

However much you want to is irrelevant. You cannot. That is not valid C++.

> Can I somehow use the const keyword for inheritance?"

No.

Comment: Any thoughts on the 2nd half, "If not, do you have any other ideas on how to solve this problem?"

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `const` member function `set`, you will get what you need.

```
class Property
{
    int get() const;
    void set(int a);
};

class ConstChild : public Property
{
    void set(int a) const {}
};
```

The only caveat is that a sly user can circumvent your intention by using:

```
ConstChild child;
child.set(10);    // Not OK by the compiler

Property& base = child;
base.set(10);    // OK by the compiler
```

Comment: and what if the `void set(int a)` was declared to be `virtual`?

Comment: Also, in addition to how trivial it is to work around, this only answers the question if the OP's "Can never call `A::set()`" actually meant 'can call it, but without anything happening'... which I kinda doubt. One would think they genuinely mean it can't be called, i.e. it would generate a compile error, like any attempt to call a non-`const` method in the kind of real `const` object to which they drew an analogy.

Comment: When the instance of `ConstChild` is `const` itself I could call its `set` method, which would make it seem like it is actually doing something, which it isn't. Ideally the line `Property& base = child;` would cause a compiler error, since it tries to cast away `const`ness.

Comment: @MartinDarterson, I don't think you can get the exact behavior you are looking for with what the language currently supports.

Comment: @MartinDarterson ...but you can achieve functionally the same thing easily using Shane's suggestion, which additionally has the benefit of stopping people from repeating "prefer composition over inheritance" to you forever ;-)

Comment: @Mike You make a good point, that this is not capable of 'masking' a `virtual` function since `const` is part of the signature and thus the derived function would not be considered to `override` the base one. Even for a non-`virtual` class, it's easy to circumvent. My instinct is that shadowing as a deliberate tool seems like a code smell... am I wrong?

Comment: I think you mean that you can do `class ConstChild : public Property
{
    void set(int a)  = delete;
};` (C++11)

Comment: @alfC, that's an option too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data member or private base class instead of public base class.

Then you control the access to that member.

You can make the Property thing an abstract interface if you need polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template class and a specialization for a constant type:

```
    template<typename T> class base_property {
    protected:
      T value;
    };
    template<typename T> class property : public base_property<T> {
    public:
      const T& get()const { return value; }
      void set(const T& v){ value = v; }
    };

    template<typename T> class property<const T> : public base_property<T> {
    public:
      const T& get()const { return value; }
    };

    class ConstChild : public property<const int>{ };
```

Comment: This is basically just creating a whole separate class in the first place. Not really in the spirit of what was asked!

Comment: but it answers the second question:  "If not, do you have any other ideas on how to solve this problem?", and can use a base class for both that contains the data

Comment: In that case why bother with the template? Just have two distinct classes. You have to reimplement them anyway.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit better now, albeit practically equivalent to existing answers.

Comment: because the data type says what specialization will use, and can use it with any data type, and if he adds an extra template parameter can use it as a friend class to acces de data member

Comment: class my_cass
{
public:
 propery<const int, my_cass> my_property; /*only my_cass can modify the value*/
};

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and I ended up with this quite manual approach :

```
class A
{
public:

    void fooMutable(void) {}
    void fooConst(void) const {}
};

class B : private A
{
public:

    using A::fooConst;
    const A& getParent(void) const
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

void fooParent(const A&) {}

int main(void)
{
    auto b = B{};
    b.fooConst(); // Ok
    b.fooMutable(); // Fail
    fooParent(b); // Fail
    fooParent(b.getParent()); // Ok

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the using keyword would not work with overloads const/mutable :

```
class A
{
public:

    void foo(void) {}
    void foo(void) const {}
};

class B : private A
{
public:

    using A::foo; // Expose the const and the mutable version
};
```

To solve this you could redefine the function yourself and call the parent :

```
class B : private A
{
public:

    void foo(void) const
    {
        A::foo();
    }
};
```

It can become pretty time consuming if you're inheriting a large hierarchy, but if it's for a not-so-big class it should be very reasonable and being quite natural for the user.

Answer (score -1):

I have a trick, not a clean solution.

```
class ConstChild : private Property
{
    operator const Property () { return *this; }
};
```

then

```
ConstChild cc;
cc.set(10); // ERROR
cc().get();
```

Comment: This is incorrect at many levels, first the conversion operator will never be called as gcc warns `warning: conversion function converting 'ConstChild' to its base class 'Property' will never be used`. Then ConstChild doesn't provide `operator()`, so `cc()` is invalid. Presumably `cc.operator const Property().get()` would be, in which case `operator const Property&` would make more sense. An even then the syntax is ugly. The only think that would make some sense is to declare `using Property::get` inside `ConstChild`.