# Can inhereted classes be made const?

Tags: c++, constants

Assume I have:

```
class dog
{
public:
    dog(int legs) : legs(legs) {};
    int legs;
};
class poodle
{
public:
    poodle(int legs) : d(dog(legs)) {};
private:
    const dog d;
};
class labrador : public dog
{
public:
    labrador(int legs) : dog(legs) {};
};
```

Is it possible to make something like `class labrador : public const dog` such that `labrador` and `poodle` behave similarly, that is, they both have a const number of legs when constructed, but using inheritance instead of storing a const member?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086698/inherit-from-const-class

Comment: Ugh, why doesn't the language support this obvious feature

Comment: @Carbon It was raised in the std-proposals forum, but IIRC, it's not that desirable of a feature. It comes up very rarely in practice, and composition is almost always what's wanted instead of inheritance.

Comment: I do like the idea somewhat, but I think the rare need is already addressed by composition with const members

Comment: The case I have is the data needs to be mutable when created then when stored in another thing becomes const, but the data provides operator< and operator==, now I have to write wrappers

Comment: Probably use a const protected method in class dog { protected: int legs() const { return 4; } }